# What is the difference between function foo(){} and foo: function(){} in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So I'm looking over a piece of code and I noticed this:

```
clickNext: function(e) {
            var cal = $(e.target).parents('.drp-calendar');
            if (cal.hasClass('left')) {
                this.leftCalendar.month.add(1, 'month');
            } else {
                this.rightCalendar.month.add(1, 'month');
                if (this.linkedCalendars)
                    this.leftCalendar.month.add(1, 'month');
            }
            this.updateCalendars();
},
```

Is this the same thing as this?

```
function clickNext(e) {
            var cal = $(e.target).parents('.drp-calendar');
            if (cal.hasClass('left')) {
                this.leftCalendar.month.add(1, 'month');
            } else {
                this.rightCalendar.month.add(1, 'month');
                if (this.linkedCalendars)
                    this.leftCalendar.month.add(1, 'month');
            }
            this.updateCalendars();
},
```

I haven't seen that kind of function declaration before and I confused because I tried changing the above the below and the code stopped working.

Comment: This is probably part of an *object literal*…!?

Comment: As @deceze stated, it's probably part of an object literal, which is essentially `var clickNext = function(e){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write function in two ways: as named function or as variable that has value as anonymous function:

```
var fooBoo = function () {};
function fooBoo(){}
```

Calling it is the same: `fooBoo()`.

---

From your example it seems that you have object with one of keys with function:

```
var myObj = {
    fooBar: function () {}
}
```

Now in this situation you **can't** replace it with `function fooBar(){}` as it would end up in wrong syntax:

```
// NOT VALID!
var myObj = {
    function fooBar() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an object property declaration:

```
const thing = {
   clickNext: function(e) {
            ...
   }
}
```

`thing.clickNext()`

It's same object literal syntax as:

```
const person = {
  name: "Jane",
  age: 33
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same things.

```
// this cannot be in itself
clickNext: function(e) {
  var cal = $(e.target).parents('.drp-calendar');
  if (cal.hasClass('left')) {
    this.leftCalendar.month.add(1, 'month');
  } else {
    this.rightCalendar.month.add(1, 'month');
    if (this.linkedCalendars)
      this.leftCalendar.month.add(1, 'month');
  }
  this.updateCalendars();
},
```

This is part of an `Object, like:

```js
const obj = {
  value1: 5,
  clickNext: function(e) {
    console.log(`${e} is your function`)
  },
  value2: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}

obj.clickNext('this')
```

This is a function in itself:

```js
// no comma at the end!!!
function clickNext(e) {
  console.log(`${e} is your function`)
}

clickNext('this')
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of declaring functions in JavaScript, it is known as Function declaration. Keys points to note:

- We call this function as function name followed by paranthesis - `clickNext()`.
- `this` keyword refers to global object inside function declaration, which means it refers to `window` object.

  `function clickNext() {
      console.log(this)  // this refers to global object window here.
  }`

Below is an example of **methods**. When we have a function inside an object, it is called as method.

- We call a method using syntax of - `dummyObject.clickNext()`
- `this` keyword refers to object in which it is declared which means in below example `this` refers to `dummyObject`.

  `const dummyObject = {
    clickNext: function(e) {
        console.log(this) // this refers to dummyObject here
    }
  };`